# Qemu asking for 'raw' format with -pflash parameter

Tags: qemu, edk2

After properly building OVMF x64 with EDK2, the command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -s -pflash run-ovmf/bios.bin -net none
```

provides the following message

```
WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'run-ovmf/bios.bin' and probing guessed raw.
         Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.
         Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.
```

This makes no sense to me as using qemu's -help command states  "-pflash file    use 'file' as a parallel flash image" where there is no parameter for a file format.

My OS is Windows WSL Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)

Qemu does still run, however I would like to run the VM without any write restrictions.

Comment: Why not just use `-bios`?

Answer (score 1):

The '-pflash' option is (like -hda and -cdrom) a legacy "convenience" option which only allows you to specify a filename and nothing else. In order to specify other sub-options like the image format type, you need to switch to use a "long-form" option, which is typically some combination of -drive and -device. In this specific case, I think you probably want:

`-drive if=pflash,file=bios.bin,format=raw`